# Active Record object based on group by count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Hi I am ROR developer and using rails 3.2.13 with Postgres database.

I have two models:

```
Question
  attr_accessible :category, :is_active, :question_text, :question_type_id, :survey_id,
                  :user_id
  has_many :abusive_questions
```

And

```
AbusiveQuestion
  attr_accessible :question_id, :user_id, :ipaddress, :posted_by

  belongs_to :question
```

From this I want to get the AbusiveQuestion which count is greater than a particular value (ex: 5).

I did the following from my rails command

```
AbusiveQuestion.count(:group=>"abusive_questions.question_id")
```

and got

```
=> {1=>1, 5=>3, 3=>1}
```

For this result, the key is the `question_id` and value is the count but, I want to get the question which value is greater then a particular dynamic value (for ex:2).

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to `join` `Question` on `AbusiveQuestion` then use a `select` and `having` to get what you want.

Something like:

```
AbusiveQuestion.select('abusive_questions.*, count(question.id) as question_count').
  joins(:questions).
  group('abusive_questions.question_id').
  having('count(abusive_questions.question_id) > 5')
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that paren, @teeg!

Comment: thanks for all of your response and @CDub . i got some problem on your query so i utilized your idea to get my result.as follows  AbusiveQuestion.joins("join questions on questions.id = abusive_questions.question_id").select('abusive_questions.question_id,count(distinct(question_id)) as question_count').group('abusive_questions.question_id').having("count(abusive_questions.question_id) > ?",limit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use having method.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having

```
x = YOUR_DYNAMIC_COUNT
AbusiveQuestion.group(:question_id).having("count_all > ?", x).count
```

Comment: You've got the right idea with the `having` clause but you don't need the `.count` part. The OP needs the actual `AbusiveQuestion` object returned, not just a count of results returned. Also the `count_all` doesn't make sense; `having` needs to execute the aggregate function in order to limit groups.